# Energy-time Heisenberg inequality and wave-function collapse

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wavefunction-collapse

Consider a two state system (2-state atom for instance) where each state corresponds to a different energy: $\left|\psi\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|0\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|1\right>$. The states $\left|0\right>$ and $\left|1\right>$ are the eigenstates of the Hamilton operator 
$\hat{\mathcal{H}}$. The corresponding eigenvalues are $E_0$ and $E_1$. Thus a measurement can have only 2 outcomes $E_0$ or $E_1$. For the first case the following collapse will occur: $\left|\psi\right> \to \left|0\right>$ and for the second case - $\left|\psi\right> \to \left|0\right>$.

As result after the measurement the system will be in a state with predefined energy i.e. without any additional experiment we can definitely say what the energy of the system is.

From the other side Energy-time Heisenberg inequality says that we can not define energy with 100% accuracy during a limited time frame.

How are the 2 statements are related each others?

Comment: I wonder whether it is possible, in a world where |0> and |1> are the only existing state of that system, to perform a measurement. If it's not the case, then the state of the system is described in a more larger eigenstates space, and the energy is still not well defined due to the interaction of the measurement with the other degrees of freedom.

Comment: We can consider as many states as we want for instance look at the following one: $\left|\psi\right> = \sum_i c_i \left|i\right>$ with $\{E_i\}$ as eigenvalues. The result will be the same. I just chose the simplest model for my example. The only case that will not work is then $\hat{\mathcal{H}}$ has continuous spectra

Comment: No; for example if you have two states of z-spin and 2 states of y-spin, they are incompatibles. If you measure z-spin with for example a Stern-Gerlach experiment, the y-spin becomes undetermined. Since you used a gradient of B along z axis, the magnetic field across y axis cannot be null. Then the energy coupling By and y-spin is undetermined.

Comment: I've got the idea. It makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system is in an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, so the state is not changing over time.

Therefore if $O$ is any observable, the probability distribution of possible outcomes of $O$ is not changing over time, and in particular the expectation value of $O$ is not changing over time.

Therefore the time until that expectation value changes by any given amount is infinite.  So in the expression 
$$\Delta E\Delta t\ge \hbar/2$$
we have $\Delta E=0$ but $\Delta t=\infty$, so we are okay.

Comment: Not quite right $\hat{\mathcal{H}}\left|\psi\right> = \frac{E_0}{\sqrt{2}}\left|0\right> + \frac{E_1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|1\right> \ne E\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|0\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|1\right>\right) = E \left|\psi\right>$. So the system is not  in an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian

Comment: @IvanMurashko:  I don't quite see the relevance of your comment.  You've made a measurement, so the system is in a state $\psi$ which is equal either to $0\rangle$ or $1\rangle$.

Comment: The $|\psi>$ you use in $\hat{H}|\psi>$ is not an eigenstate of the Hamiltionian, because it's taken before the wave function collapse, so  $\hat{H}|\psi>=E|\psi>$ is wrong. Only after the measurement, the considered system is an eigenstate of the Hamiltionian.

Comment: The $|\psi>$ you use in $\hat{H}|\psi>$ is not an eigenstate of the Hamiltionian, because it's taken before the wave function collapse, so  $\hat{H}|\psi>=E|\psi>$ is wrong. Only after the measurement, the considered system is in an eigenstate of the Hamiltionian.After the measurement $|\psi>=|0>$ or $|\psi>=|1>$, so then, $\hat{H}|\psi>=\hat{H}|0>=E_0|0>$ or $\hat{H}|\psi>=\hat{H}|1>=E_1|1>$. The "weird" thing about the collapse of the wave function is, that the system changes completely, i.e. the resulting wave function has nothing anymore to do with the original wave function.

Comment: @Willo My idea is that the system initially prepared in the state with undefined energy that is in the good relation with Heisenberg inequality (as soon as it is not an eigenstate of Hamiltonian). But after the measurement it transferred into the state with defined energy (that is not allowed accordingly Heisenberg inequality).

Comment: @IvanMurashko:  But it **is** allowed.   I don't see why you say it's not.  What is an example of a state $\psi$ in which you think that $\Delta E\Delta t$ is violated?   Try writing down that state explicitly, computing $\Delta E$ and $\Delta t$, and you'll see that the inequality holds.  My answer already does this for you in the case where $\psi$ is an energy eigenstate, i.e. if you've just measured the energy, as your original question called for.

Comment: @Willo, I just understood your point. You say about the system after the measurement. In this case the energy is not changed i.e. $\Delta E = 0$. But I am not sure that $\Delta t = \infty$. My filling is that $\Delta t$ is the time that was spent for $E$ estimation i.e. in the case $\Delta t = 0$.

Comment: @Ivan: $\Delta t$ is the time it takes for some other observable's expectation value to change by (roughly) one standard deviation.  If that expectation value is not changing, then $\Delta t$ is infinite. I don't know where you got the "feeling" that $\Delta t$ is "the time spent for $E$ estimation", so I can't explain where you went wrong, but your notion has nothing whatsoever to do with the actual  meaning of $\Delta t$.

Comment: @Willo (I just rewritten my deleted comment) if we have the measurement ($\left|\psi\right> \to \left|0\right>$) at time $t_1$  then we can change it some later without any trouble. The time for change also can be chosen. For instance at $t_2$ we can start converting the state into $\left|1\right>$ and finish the process at $t_3$. In this case we have defined energy $E_0$ only during the limited timeframe $\Delta t = t_2 - t_1 < \infty$.

Comment: @Ivan Marasko:  the fact that you used the same notation $\Delta t$ to represent two different things does not imply that those two things satisfy the same inequalities.

Comment: @Willo, I've got your idea and have to think about it. May be you are right and my feeling about the inequality was wrong

Comment: @ivanmurashko Let me suggest that, more generally, physics does not have to respect your (or anyone's) "feelings".  If you think something should be true, try to prove it.  If you can't prove it, don't assume it's true.

Comment: @Willo I just looked at the proof for the Energy-Time Heisenberg inequality (should do it before the asking the question) the answer seems to be acceptable for me. As I understood the $\Delta t$ is really connected with the state and the inequality holds only until the state not changed.